# TypeORM - Generic entity creation

Tags: typescript, generics, typeorm

I am trying to generalize my entity creation system in the context of a CRUD system, to avoid redundant code duplication.

The base class `CrudController<T>` should provide a generic method `createEntity(data)`, that creates and returns an entity with the given data. The data is of type `Partial<T>`.

In my derived class `StateController`, which extends `CrudController<State>` I implemented this as:

```
protected createEntity(data: Partial<State>): Promise<State> {
    const repository = getRepository(State);
    const entity = repository.create(data);
    return repository.save(entity);
}
```

... which works flawlessly. However, when I try to generalize this into the base class with something like:

```
protected createEntity(data: Partial<T>): Promise<T> {
    const repository = getRepository(this.entityType);
    const entity = repository.create(data);
    return repository.save(entity);
}
```

... I run into TypeScript complaining that no overload matches the call. I understand that the signature of `Repository.create(...)` expects a `DeepPartial<T>` rather than a simple `Partial<T>`, but this worked fine for the non-generalize method, so why wouldn't it here?

Is there some type constraint on the generic, that I am missing?